# How do I make a custom 'File not found(404, 500)[http error code]'for my website

Tags: html, web, http-status-code-404, http-error, file-not-found

I have seen some websites have their own File not found pages with their logos.

I want such a page for my website.

Please tell me how to make a such type of page that shows the user if the file is not found.

Comment: Which language or framework using in your website?

Comment: html,css,php,js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need an HTML or PHP file to show when the 404 is occurs. Let's do a simple HTML file like this:

```
<h2> 404 Not Found! </h2>
<pre> Seems like the resource you're looking for is not found </pre>
```

Let's call this file 404.html.

Now you have to configure your webserver to redirect the not found request to your new HTML document.

**If you're using Apache:**

You can do it in different ways, the most common and recommended would be using `.htaccess` file, which allows you to override Apache configuration of a virtual host. However, to be able to use the .htaccess file in your virtual hosts you need to add `allowOverride all` inside your apache configuration.

*Example of apache config:*

```
<Directory /path/to/your/project>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All # This is the needed option
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

So now you're able to put a .htaccess file in your project, so just create it and put this inside:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/404.html/document
```

**In case you're using Nginx:**

You must add the error page inside the nginx configuration. Follow this guide in order to achieve it:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-to-use-custom-error-pages-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Apache server 
in your project folder 
consider your project is in

```
/mySampleProject
```

create `.htaccess` file in `/mySampleProject` if you don't have one.

simply add this line in your .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /yourCustom404Template.html
```

Comment: i cannot understand, it means is it like this example.htaccess

Comment: Nope,open cmd in your project directory and enter this command "echo "ErrorDocument 404 /yourCustom404Template.html
" > .htaccess"

Comment: i am running on localhost

Comment: @SakithKarunasena if you want to build this type of things you need at least to use php, so you need apache

Comment: In xampp/htdocs/your_project_folder/ open cmd and use the above command i mentioned

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest you, use a framework of whatever programming language you want to build this application. They have in-built custom arrangements for such requirement e.g.

if( *file_not_found Logic* ){ 
       show 404_page
   }